# How to stretch text like this in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography

I rasterized text and apply free transform and distort but can't stretch text like partial like this. (PS. I did this, but forgot what effect I applied... haha)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this (sorry for flipping it and having low resolution):

[image]

The uppermost line is the original text, but rasterized

In the middle a copy is warped wit arc warp preset. Bend=0%, but there's 50% horizontal distortion.

In the bottom line perspective is added.

You can add both distortions in the same Edit > Transform session and get a little better result because you avoid one re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

At any point in history panel, if this is this available then you can revert back to that state by pressing `ctrl + alt + z` several times until you get there.

If history panel is not available then you can show by going to view menu and click on history. Basically history panel is snapshot of all the time when you do some operations in the document so that we can revert back to any particular if we need to.

Apart from that there is no option to tell exactly what effect and transformations have been applied and in which order to make it look like this.

May be you have distorted and applied some bevel/embass effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the stretch is non-uniform. You can achieve that with three tools that I can think of:

1. Warp transform (Edit > Transform > Warp).
2. Liquify (Filter > Liquify).
3. Puppet warp (Edit > Puppet warp). Like Warp, but on steroids - allows you to define many more control points to move.

Hint: You don't need to rasterize the text - you can wrap the text layer in a smart object. Thus you can change the text at any point, and the distortion will be applied accordingly.

I think in the example provided you had used the simplest method of the three - Warp.

Answer (score 0):

Played with this a bit and came up with a different solution than above.
Using your image as a guideline, set your type and change tracking/kerning so that the letters are tight together:

[image]

Then right click on your type layer and rasterize your type.

Using your selection tool, choose the last three letters of your word:

[image]

With the selection active, now choose your move tool so that all the handles show:

[image]

Now with the Shift key held down, start pulling on the center handle to stretch out those last three letters:

[image]

Now play with the letters however you want. Hold down shift to pull out, hold down ALT to give it height, hold down SHIFT + ALT to stretch and give it height at once.
Do three letters, two letters, or one letter until you get the effect you want.

[image]

Maybe not the most efficient one-button way of doing things but I've never been accused of being efficient... :)